# \includegraphics claims file is not found, but then it finds the file---how to fix it?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

Using `\includegraphics` with TeXLive 2020 (from Debian Bullseye, current stable), I'm including a graphics file.
The file is incorporated correctly and the output looks as I expect, but nevertheless I get a warning saying the file is not found.  I'd like to figure out how to eliminate that warning.

A MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

The target is {\includegraphics[height=20pt]{target.epsi}}.

\end{document}
```

The output in the log file looks like this:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `target.epsi' not found on input line 6.

File: target.epsi Graphic file (type eps)
<target.epsi>
[1

] (./mwe-epsi.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
```

I have placed the `target.epsi` file in a pastebin at https://pastebin.com/raw/xVnc1WMd.

Comment: I get the warning in texlive 2020, in texlive 2021 it works.

Comment: For the record, it was issue [#516](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/516)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik if you'll kindly write an answer I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are seeing is similar to what was initially reported [here](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2021-March/046525.html) (issue [#516](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/516)):  when a graphics file extension is unknown and it is loaded using the generic rule (available by default in DVI mode:  when you run `latex` instead of `pdflatex`), a spurious warning would be issued saying that the file was not found.  Although completely harmless, it was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/ab0cb06c45dd7beca0569a1b4004e5a1d5de0a70), available in LaTeX 2021-06-01.  Updating should solve the issue.

If you are stuck with an older release and want to get rid of the warning, you can use `etoolbox` to patch `\Ginclude@graphics` and change the three lines of code shown [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/ab0cb06c45dd7beca0569a1b4004e5a1d5de0a70), but I recommend you don't:  the warning is completely harmless, so just ignoring it until you update is the best solution.